# JavaScript / Html Pl/sql validator.

Tags: javascript, html, validation, c#-4.0, plsql

I am creating an application where the user can enter html / Javascript and PL/SQL code, which will be stored in the Database. I want to validate the syntax for this languages before storing them in the database. 
I am using C# language for the application. 
I would like to know if there is any library that i can use to acheive

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), which defines itself as a ".NET Language Implementation Kit". It works really great. I used it for a simpler task, though: converting user searches into a SQL-Server `CONTAINS`-compatible expressions, as described in [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+%282008%29/64248/) (which may be a good starting point to understand what Irony does).

Here is their project description on Codeplex:

> **Irony** is a development kit for implementing languages on .NET platform. Unlike most existing yacc/lex-style solutions Irony does not employ any scanner or parser code generation from grammar specifications written in a specialized meta-language. In Irony the target language grammar is coded directly in c# using operator overloading to express grammar constructs. Irony's scanner and parser modules use the grammar encoded as c# class to control the parsing process.

So, it's "officially" a tool for language *implementation*, but you can totally use it just for syntax validation.